# Is there a way to validate data between 2 or more regex expressions using Zod?

Tags: javascript, validation, zod

I have something like this:

```
const regexOne = <regex>
const regexTwo = <regex>
const regexThree = <regex>

const Schema = z.object({
  validation: z.string().toUpperCase().union([z.regex(regexOne), z.regex(regexTwo), z.regex(RegexThree)])
})
```

But I am not having success. Any suggestions on how I can validate data from an input using either one of the regex expressions?

I tried also separating 3 different schemas, each one with one regex rule. But I had no success yet.

Comment: Should the uppercase string schema be an alternative to the three regexes, or does it need to validate together with any of the three regexes? It's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. Adding a few examples of valid and invalid inputs, as well as three examples for the regexes, would help - please [edit] your question to include them.

Answer (score 0):

```
const z = require('zod');

const regex1 = /[a-z]+/;
const regex2 = /[0-9]+/;

const schema = z.string().intersection(regex1, regex2);

const validData = 'abc123';
const invalidData = 'abc';

console.log(schema.parse(validData)); // Output: 'abc123'
console.log(schema.parse(invalidData)); // Throws ZodError
```

Yes, it's possible to validate data against multiple regex expressions using Zod. To achieve this, you can use the `Zod.intersection` method to combine the regex expressions into a single schema.

First, define the regex expressions you want to use in the validation process. Then, create a `Zod.string()` schema and use the `Zod.intersection` method to combine the regex expressions into this schema. You can then use the `parse` method to validate the data against the schema.

If the provided data passes all the checks defined in the schema, the parse method returns the validated data. If the data fails any of the checks, a ZodError will be thrown.

Comment: Can you share where the `intersection` method you're using is defined? As far as I can see that method does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think you are looking for `z.union` to combine several `z.string()` schemas into a single schema. For example

```js
import { z } from 'zod';

// Good to match the beginning and end of a string if you want the full string
// to match
const regexOne = /^1$/;
const regexTwo = /^2$/;
const regexThree = /^3$/;

const s1 = z.string().regex(regexOne);
const s2 = z.string().regex(regexTwo);
const s3 = z.string().regex(regexThree);

const schema = z.union([s1, s2, s3]);
```

[Documentation on `z.union`](https://zod.dev/?id=unions)

Another answer mentioned using `z.intersection` which is the alternative option. `z.union` will succeed if one of the regexes matches. `z.intersection` will succeed only if all regexes match. Rather than using `z.intersection` for multiple regexes that must all match, you could also chain multiple class to `.regex()` after the base `z.string()` schema.

---

**Aside**: I noticed in your question that you are attempting to call `union` directly on the schema returned by `z.string()` but as far as I can tell that method does not exist on `ZodString`. Nor is `z.regex` an exported schema from what I can see.